# Successfully implement MapLike in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm having a dastard of a time implementing a Map in scala typed to (for our purposes) [String, Set[Foo]] that provides extra operations for the Foos in the values. The actual implementation is more complicated than presented below, but this is the gist.  I need a class that implements all the Map-like functions and provides the extra-and-above aggregation on the collections that are the values of the map.  The extends Map with MapLike patterns I've seen, particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165925/convert-java-util-identityhashmap-to-scala-immutable-map), are not working.

What I've got so far:

```
import scala.collection.{immutable, Map, MapLike}

class Foo(a:Int) 

class CustomMap
 (val underlying:Map[String,Set[Foo]] = Map[String,Set[Foo]]())
 extends Map[String, Set[Foo]] with MapLike[String, Set[Foo], CustomMap] {
  override def empty = new CustomMap(underlying.empty)

  def -(key: String) = new CustomMap(underlying - key)

  def +[B1 >: Set[Foo]](kv: (String, B1)): scala.collection.Map[String,B1] = new CustomMap(underlying + (kv._1 -> kv._2))

  def get(key: String): Option[Set[Foo]] = underlying.get(key)

  def iterator: Iterator[(String, Set[Foo])] = underlying.iterator

  override def size = underlying.size

  def getAllFoos() = underlying.values.flatten.toSet
}

val cm1:CustomMap = new CustomMap(Map("a" -> Set(new Foo(1))))
val cm2:CustomMap = cm1 + ("a" -> Set(new Foo(2)))
println(cm2.getAllFoos)
```

There are issues both with the + method and accessing the extra aggregate methods.

Any pointers?

```
file.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : B1
 required: Set[this.Foo]
  def +[B1 >: Set[Foo]](kv: (String, B1)): scala.collection.Map[String,B1] = new CustomMap(underlying + (kv._1 -> kv._2))
                                                                                                                     ^
file.scala:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.Map[String,Set[this.Foo]]
 required: this.CustomMap
val cm2:CustomMap = cm1 + ("a" -> Set(new Foo(2)))
                        ^
two errors found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` can't return a `CustomMap` because sometimes `B1` won't be a `Set[Foo]` but some other supertype of `Set[Foo]`. This is the source of your errors. `Map` and `MapLike` are meant for classes that provide a map implementation that could safely have any value added to it and will return a usable `Map`. So a `Map[String, Set[Foo]]` can always have an `("", 5)` put into it and become a `Map[String, Any]`.

You can eliminate the wrapper around your `underlying`, as well as avoid these problems, by using the "pimp-my-library" pattern:

```
implicit class FooSetMap(val map: Map[String,Set[Foo]]) extends AnyVal {
  def getAllFoos = map.values.flatten.toSet
}
```

If you are willing to use a mutable map, take a look at `collection.mutable.MultiMap`. It is a mixin trait which adds extra methods to subtypes of `mutable.Map[A, mutable.Set[B]]` for working with multimaps - you could do something similar for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still supporting Scala 2.9, so I don't have access to implicits.  I've ended up using the MultiMap pattern you pointed out.  It'll work until we move up to 2.10.  Thanks!

Comment: The implicit pimp-my-library pattern can still be done in 2.9, but not with value classes (`extends AnyVal`) and you have to define a separate `implicit def` rather than using `implicit class`.